# MIPI Camera programing in Windows 8.1 Tablet

Tags: windows, camera, tablet

Who know how to write a Camera App of Windows Form on Windows Tablet with two cameras, and not using C#?
And Now Intel Baytrail-T CR now using MIPI, and no any windows desktop camera app to do preview.
So, does any body know how to?

Comment: If you state your technical problem here, you may get answer quick. This question is generic, and not sure what specific help you required here.

Comment: http://git.oschina.net/tody_guo/webcam    this app can fix my request. New function of